# Menu in Zurb foundation not work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I start as a back-end developer, I know a little about front-end. At this weekend, I do a stuff as a hobby then stuck at here.
 I follow this tutorial: http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/menu-bar
I don't know why the menu display incorrect:

Source HTML `view-source:http://localhost:8080/vyhndotnet/registration.jsp#`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Developer life</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/vyhndotnet/css/foundation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/vyhndotnet/css/app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/vyhndotnet/foundation-icon-font-3/foundation-icons.css" />
    <script>$(document).foundation();</script>
</head>
<body>

        <ul class="dark menu-bar">
            <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Core Java</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JSP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hibernate</a></li>
        </ul>


<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <h3>Đăng ký thành viên</h3>
        <form action="/vyhndotnet/Registration" method="post">
            <label>Tên đăng nhập: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" />

            <label>Số điện thoại: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="mobile_number" />

            <label>Email: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="email" /> 

            <label>Quốc gia: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="nation" />


            <button class="small button" type="reset"><i class="fi-loop"></i>&nbsp;Làm lại</button>
            <button class="small button" type="submit"><i class="fi-key"></i>&nbsp;Đăng ký</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<a href="../../index.jsp" class="medium button"><i class="fi-home"></i>&nbsp;Homepage</a>
<br />
Copyright &copy; 2016 VyHN
</body>
</html>
```

result:
[image]

(foundation.min.css load correctly, not broken link)
Help me display menu use Zurb foundation correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I would expect `<script>$(function() { $(document).foundation(); });</script>`

Comment: @mplungjan I follow your suggest, but it still not work.

Comment: I am sorry. I have a mistake, this tutorial for `web apps` ( http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/menu-bar ), not for `web page`. But I still want display menu in Zurb foundation way correctly.

Comment: You linked to the Foundation for Apps docs but your tags say this question is about Foundation for Sites. Those are two separate frameworks, which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>`

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="v_menu">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href="#">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CORE JAVA</a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">OOP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Collections</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">JSP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WEB SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HIBERNATE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then result:
[image]
Reference:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html#horizontal 
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html